# Animating a rotating ring of sprites

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, cube, morphing

I want to make an application for iOS , i have some expertise in cocos2d.I have searched a lot but all i found was CSS implementation of this animation using webkit, i dont know any other language except C,Objective C, VHDL.

1-How can i make this animation in cocos2d or on any other FrameWork.

2-how can i make it interactive(with touches).

i can make it interactive but i need pointers to how to make this animation.what i have in mind is to manually scale and move each sprite and change there opacity, to creat this effect but it will take a lot of time .

here is the link with the animation

https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/morphing-cubes.html

Comment: i dont have enough points, so i cant upload a picture.

Comment: i doubt very much you will be able to do that with cocos2d, or any other 2d framework for that matter.

Comment: what do you recommend then ?

Comment: not 3d savvy myself, however i found this that may have some relevance. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48626/3d-transformation-of-game-world-keeping-gameplay-2d-cocos2d-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did that Using cocos3d , using the demomashup as my  starting point and then i looked into its "skinnyrunner" method and modified the cube die method here is my code

```
// Create the camera, place it back a bit, and add it to the scene
CC3Camera* cam = [CC3Camera nodeWithName: @"Camera"];
cam.location = cc3v(0.0, 0.0, 200.0);
[self addChild: cam];

// Create a light, place it back and to the left at a specific
// position (not just directional lighting), and add it to the scene
CC3Light* lamp = [CC3Light nodeWithName: @"Lamp"];
lamp.location = cc3v(-110.0, 110.0, 50.0);
lamp.isDirectionalOnly = NO;
[cam addChild: lamp];


// Fetch the die cube model from the POD file.
CC3PODResourceNode* podRezNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeFromFile: kDieCubePODFile];
CC3Node* podDieCube = [podRezNode getNodeNamed: kDieCubePODName];

// We want this node to be a SpinningNode class instead of the CC3PODNode class that
// is loaded from the POD file. We can swap it out by creating a copy of the loaded
// POD node, using a different node class as the base.
dieCube = [[podDieCube copyWithName: kDieCubeName
                            asClass: [SpinningNode class]] autorelease];

// Now set some properties, including the friction, and add the die cube to the scene


CCSprite        * markerSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"IMG1.PNG"];
marker = [CC3Billboard nodeWithName: @"TouchSpot" withBillboard: markerSprite];


CCSprite        * markerSprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"IMG2.PNG"];
marker1 = [CC3Billboard nodeWithName: @"TouchSpot1" withBillboard: markerSprite1];


CCSprite        * markerSprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"IMG3.PNG"];
marker2 = [CC3Billboard nodeWithName: @"TouchSpot2" withBillboard: markerSprite2];


CCSprite        * markerSprite3 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"IMG4.PNG"];
marker3 = [CC3Billboard nodeWithName: @"TouchSpot3" withBillboard: markerSprite3];

CCSprite        * markerSprite4 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"IMG5.png"];
marker4 = [CC3Billboard nodeWithName: @"TouchSpot4" withBillboard: markerSprite4];


CCSprite        * markerSprite5 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"IMG2.PNG"];
marker5 = [CC3Billboard nodeWithName: @"TouchSpot5" withBillboard: markerSprite5];


CCSprite        * markerSprite6 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"IMG3.PNG"];
marker6 = [CC3Billboard nodeWithName: @"TouchSpot6" withBillboard: markerSprite6];


CCSprite        * markerSprite7 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"IMG4.PNG"];
marker7 = [CC3Billboard nodeWithName: @"TouchSpot7" withBillboard: markerSprite7];







float scale=0.15;

//  marker.scale = cc3v(0.0001f, 0.0001f, 0.0001f);
marker.location = cc3v(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0);
marker.uniformScale=scale;
marker.isTouchEnabled = YES;

marker1.location = cc3v(35.0, 0.0f, 35.0);
marker1.uniformScale=scale;
marker1.isTouchEnabled = YES;


marker2.location = cc3v(50, 0.0f, 0.0f);
marker2.uniformScale=scale;
marker2.isTouchEnabled = YES;

marker3.location = cc3v(35, 0.0f, -35.0f);
marker3.uniformScale=scale;
marker3.isTouchEnabled = YES;

marker4.location = cc3v(0.0f, 0.0f, -50.0f);
marker4.uniformScale=scale;
marker4.isTouchEnabled = YES;

marker5.location = cc3v(-35.0f, 0.0f, -35.0f);
marker5.uniformScale=scale;
marker5.isTouchEnabled = YES;


marker6.location = cc3v(-50.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
marker6.uniformScale=scale;
marker6.isTouchEnabled = YES;

marker7.location = cc3v(-35.0f, 0.0f, 35.0f);
marker7.uniformScale=scale;
marker7.isTouchEnabled = YES;

marker.rotation = cc3v(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
marker1.rotation = cc3v(0.0f,45.0f,  0.0f);

marker2.rotation = cc3v(0.0f,90.0f,  0.0f);
marker3.rotation = cc3v(0.0f, 130.0f, 0.0f);
marker4.rotation = cc3v(0.0f, 180.0f, 0.0f);
marker5.rotation = cc3v(0.0f, 225.0f, 0.0f);
marker6.rotation = cc3v(0.0f, 270.0f, 0.0f);

marker7.rotation = cc3v(0.0f,  315.0f,0.0f);





CC3Node* runningTrack = [CC3Node nodeWithName: kRunningTrackName];
runningTrack.location = cc3v(0.0, 10.0, 0.0);;
[self addChild: runningTrack];

CCActionInterval* runLap = [CC3RotateBy actionWithDuration: 10.0 rotateBy: cc3v(0.0, 360.0, 0.0)];
[runningTrack runAction: [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: runLap]];

 [runningTrack addChild:marker];
 [runningTrack addChild:marker1];
 [runningTrack addChild:marker2];
 [runningTrack addChild:marker3];
[runningTrack addChild:marker4];
[runningTrack addChild:marker5];
[runningTrack addChild:marker6];
[runningTrack addChild:marker7];

//[self addChild: dieCube];
```

}

even though i am new to cocos3d , but if you think i can help dont hesitate to ask.
Karim